# Recover crack unzip Zip 2.0 (Legacy) file with lost password on Linux

Tags: zip, unzip, forgot-password, recover, cracking

I have an old zip file with a lost password.

`zipinfo -z` tells me its version Zip 2.0 which uses PKWARE encryption. Good news as that's apparently weak.

Bad news is nothing I've searched & founds tells me if its possible to crack without using brute force.

[PKCrack](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~conrad/krypto/pkcrack/pkcrack-readme.html) looked like an option but it requires an unencrypted version of one of the files which I don't have.

I tried [fcrackzip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fcrackzip.1.html) with a dictionary but it seems I don't remember anything about the password.

Does anyone know a good method to recover or unzip the files or the password or crack the zip without using brute force?

I believe it was encrypted on Windows - probably XP. I'm now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Here's the zipinfo -v output:

```
offset of local header from start of archive:   10089220 (000000000099F304h) bytes
file system or operating system of origin:      NTFS
version of encoding software:                   2.0
minimum file system compatibility required:     MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
minimum software version required to extract:   2.0
compression method:                             deflated
compression sub-type (deflation):               normal
file security status:                           encrypted
extended local header:                          no
file last modified on (DOS date/time):          2004 Feb 19 14:13:00
32-bit CRC value (hex):                         498a9daf
compressed size:                                39271 bytes
uncompressed size:                              39855 bytes
length of filename:                             16 characters
length of extra field:                          0 bytes
length of file comment:                         0 characters
disk number on which file begins:               disk 1
apparent file type:                             binary
non-MSDOS external file attributes:             000000 hex
MS-DOS file attributes (20 hex):                arc
```

Thank you for any help - these files are important to me

Comment: The plaintext attack does not necessarily need the complete file. You need at least 13 known plaintext bytes to perform the attack.

Comment: Thanks @bookmarc but that's just it, I don't have anything other than the filenames. Presumably they can't count towards the plaintext byte count. Otherwise I have zilch. Looks like I'll have to resort to brute force. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fcrackzip` using the `RockYou.txt` password list.

```
fcrackzip -v -u -D -p PATH/rockyou.txt NAME_OF_ZIP.zip
```

- `-v`: for verbose mode.
- `-u`: for weed out wrong passwords.
- `-D`: for using a dictionary.
- `-p`: for using a string as a password.

https://github.com/brannondorsey/naive-hashcat/releases/download/data/rockyou.txt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however fcrackzip runs for a few seconds then exits without comment. 

I notice from the man page the password file should be sorted so I ran `sort rockyou.txt -o rockyou.sorted.txt` and used that file as the dict however same results - it runs for a few seconds, I can see "Trying password xxxxx" then exits. No log, no files output.

I'm using fcrackzip version 1.0 on Ububtu 22.04

Comment: stdout from fcrackzip is

`found file 'Thesis_main.DOC', (size cp/uc 1654281/1667910, flags 1, chk 94e4)
found file 'Thesis_main1.DOC', (size cp/uc 1958394/1974979, flags 1, chk 8905)
...
found file 'Ref1.DOC', (size cp/uc 426546/427386, flags 1, chk 5282)
found file 'Bib1.DOC', (size cp/uc 364697/365597, flags 1, chk 2ee6)
8 file maximum reached, skipping further files`

stderr is empty